# How to use fopen and fwrite that will read, replace and add something on a text file?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, fopen, fwrite

At first, I have a program which can read and add something on a text file. Now, what I want to do is to select all the data from database table and open, copy and replace and add something on the text file. It was just like I select all (ctrl+a) the content of the text file and then paste it but with added something.

```
$fileArray = file($filename);
//acl 10-0146-506_lp arp 00:15:af:a5:68:b1
$findthis = "#endofpart1\r\n";
$myKey = array_search($findthis,$fileArray);
array_splice($fileArray,$myKey,0,"acl ".$sn."_".$dd." arp ".$ma."\r\n");
//http_access allow 09-0651-410_cp
$findthis2 = "#endofpart2\r\n";
$myKey2 = array_search($findthis2,$fileArray);
array_splice($fileArray,$myKey2,0,"http_access allow ".$sn."_".$dd."\r\n");


$fp = fopen($filename,'w');

foreach($fileArray as $value) {
    fwrite($fp,$value);
}

fclose($fp);
```

This code was the first program I did.

Comment: Can you try to explain your problem differently? What have you tried?

Comment: "was just like I select all (ctrl+a) the content of the text file and then paste it" where do you want to paste it ?????

Comment: What is the actual question? Your code appears t do exactly what you want...?

Comment: actually.. that's the old code i did. what i was trying to do now is different. What i was trying to do now is select all the information in database table and then opens the squid2.conf file, copies and replace the content with the current database table stuffs. see my codes: https://www.dropbox.com/s/panhycr8og6y02i/codes.zip that save3.php is what i'm trying to do now. i didn't know what code should i do next.
you can message me on facebook: http://www.facebook.com/hunterryz

btw thanks everyone for all the help. :)

Comment: ok now i'm quite close. here's the updated saving of the code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6eg0goe87qhctgl/fileGenerate2.php
my problem is, it can only get one table.